# Angular RC6 - create injectable service with own data

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I have a data model (should be single instance in application)

```js
export class Computer {
    model: string;
    serial: string;
    completed: boolean = false;
}
```

I think the best approach would be to return it through injectable service.

```js
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    getComputer(): Observable<Computer> {
        let c = new Computer();
        c.model = 'Quite Good Computer 455';
        c.serial = '344-344-455-555';
        c.ompleted = true;
        ...
    }
}
```

It should be located in CoreModule.

How to implement DataService.getComputer() to return Observable ? The *c* created just before ...

**edit**

In this `getComputer()` method I need to emulate network latency - set timeout for 2s. Previously I was using `Promise` and this function was:

```js
getComputer(): Promise<Computer> {
    return new Promise<Computer>(resolve =>
        setTimeout(() => resolve(this.createComputer()), 2000) // 2 seconds
    );
}

private createComputer(): Computer {
    let c = new Computer();
    c.model = 'Quite Good Computer 455';
    c.serial = '344-344-455-555';
    c.ompleted = true;
    return c;
}
```

It was consumed like this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getComputer().then(
        data => this.computer = data
    );
}
```

Now I want to translate it into using Observables and later put inot core module.

After Günter Zöchbauer answer I tried following

```js
getComputer(): Observable<Computer> {
    let res = new BehaviorSubject<Computer>();
    return <Observable<Computer>>res.asObservable();
}
```

but VSC highlights line `let res ...` with error message `[ts] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. (alias) new BehaviorSubject<T>(_value: T): BehaviorSubject<T>`. I imported `BehaviorSubject` from `rxjs/rx`.

**edit**

After another note from Günter Zöchbauer I changed the service class code

```js
export class DataServiceMock {
    private computerObs: Observable<Computer>;
    constructor() {
        let s = new BehaviorSubject<Computer>();
        this.computerObs = s.asObservable(); 
    }  

    getComputer(): Observable<Computer> {
        return this.computerObs;
    }
```

Now the mentioned error is in here: `let s = new BehaviorSubject<Computer>();`. In this scenario I also don't know how to add `Computer` instance to stream (using `next()`) with 2 seconds delay - I'd put it in `ngInit`.

Comment: I think the `BehaviorSubject` constructor requires a value, that's why it throws the error, see https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/ts/core/subjects/behaviorsubject.ts#L20

Answer (score 2):

```
getComputer(): Observable<Computer> {
    let c = new Computer();
    c.model = 'Quite Good Computer 455';
    c.serial = '344-344-455-555';
    c.ompleted = true;
    return Observable.of(c);
}
```

**update**

```
private computer = new BehaviorSubject<Computer>();

computer$ = this.computer.asObservable();

// called when computer changes
updateComputer(Computer c) {
  this.computer.next(c);
}
```

used by the caller

```
this.dataService.computer$.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: How about subscribers which subscribe after this first data is emitted ?

Comment: I updated my question. Not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: In VSC I typed in `getComputer()`: `let res = new BehaviorSubject<Computer>();` and I have it underlined as error `[ts] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. (alias) new BehaviorSubject<T>(_value: T): BehaviorSubject<T>`. I import `BehaviorSubject` from `rxjs/rx`, tried from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'` and same result.

Comment: I don't posted any code like `let res = ...`. What do you try to accomplish? Can you please edit your question and add more details there. Code in comments is quite cumbersome to read.

Comment: I extended my question.

Comment: Why did you change the code from my answer to the one you added to your question? No you create a new observable for every call to `getComputer()` instead using one observable instance to notify every subscriber about changes with one call to `next()`.